# C# method overload with params and optionals

Tags: c#, .net, parameters

Today I discovered something strange. I wonder why this works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ExampleMethod(3));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string ExampleMethod(int required, params int[] optionalint)
{
    return "ExampleMethod 2";
}

public static string ExampleMethod(int required, string optionalstr = "default string", int optionalint = 10) 
{
    return "ExampleMethod 1";
}
```

Think about it: What is the result when you call ExampleMethod(3);

In my opinion it leads to an unpredictable result. In my case always Method 1 was called. But as I changed the signature of Method 1, the Main Method called Method 2 (of course).

I did not expect such a behavior, I expected an "AmbiguousReferenceException" or at least a compiler warning.

Comment: Short answer: because the spec says so. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd expect this behaviour because the compiler knows the default values of `optionalstr` and `optionalint` and is therefore able to make a decision based on that on what values to use. It wouldn't know what to set as the value for `int[] optionalint`. Since the compiler is "more sure" of what to use when you have the optional parameters, it calls that method.

If you added an extra method like this

```
public static string ExampleMethod(int required)
{
    return "ExampleMethod 3";
}
```

this would be the method called because the compiler will go for the method that has no optional parameters first.

[More detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190248/how-does-c-sharp-choose-with-ambiguity-and-params) on overload resolution.

Comment: The rules for which overload resolution are pretty detailed. This answer to a similar question has some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190248/how-does-c-sharp-choose-with-ambiguity-and-params

Comment: Thanks, I've added the link to the answer.

Comment: aaah, ok that makes sense. Thank you. I didn't think so far, that in one version the parameters were implicitly set.

Comment: @baschdy - You're welcome. Kevin has posted a good link with more details on how the compiler resolves overloads.